# Flex items leaves extra space on cross axis when parent has bigger heights

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The height of the flex container is `550px`, I have total 10 flex items. Height and width of each flex item is `70px`.

Here is the full html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flexbox</title>
    <style>
        * {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            width: 40vw;
            margin: 1rem auto;
        }

        .container {
            width: 100%;
            border: 2px solid red;
            padding: 1rem;
        }

        .item {
            border: 2px solid green;
            padding: 1rem;
            margin-right: 1rem;
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
            width: 70px;
            height: 70px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="helloFlex">
        <div class="container" style="display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;height: 550px;"> <div class="item">
            <span>1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <span>2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <span>3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <span>4</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item"><span>5</span></div>
        <div class="item"><span>6</span></div>
        <div class="item"><span>7</span></div>
        <div class="item"><span>8</span></div>
        <div class="item"><span>9</span></div>
        <div class="item"><span>10</span></div>
         </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Here is how it looks like
[image: Flex container is in red border and flex items are in green border]

Flex container is in red border and flex items are in green border.

My question is why **there is so much extra space after flex item 5** ??

If I remove the `height:550px` from `container` div, then it looks normal. Like this

[image]

Comment: the reason why after 5th element there is some space is that items has a fixed dimension 70px in your case, the next element does not fit a space that is less than that and goes into another line. for your result use `align-content: flex-start;` in the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify how you want the elements to align themselves, you can do that by using the `align-content` property on the flexbox container

```css
#helloFlex div {
  align-content: flex-start;
}
```